# AntD Error: JSX element type 'Card' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, user-interface, antd

I am trying to use AntD's card component like so:

```
import { Card, Col, Row } from 'antd';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
   <Row gutter={16}>
    <Col span={8}>
     <Card title="Card title" bordered={false}>
      Card content
     </Card>
    </Col>
   </Row>
);
}

export default App;
```

But the card component gives this error: "AntD Error: JSX element type 'Card' does not have any construct or call signatures."

I see people have had this error occur before, but not with AntD, I have tried various solutions but nothing seems to work, please help!

Answer (score 0):

Updating antd using

`npm install antd@latest`

fixed it for me.